# Can't import Antd single component without messing up with the global style

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, antd

I'd like to import a few components from the `Ant Design React CSS library` but I can't manage to get it working. I want to be able to import a single component without it messing up with the rest of my `CSS`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
import Button from 'antd/lib/button';
import 'antd/lib/button/style';
```

===> does not import the style.

```
import Button from 'antd/lib/button';
import 'antd/lib/button/style/css';
```

===> works, but messes up with the rest of the App

I have tried to do what is written [here, import AntD on demand](https://ant.design/docs/react/getting-started#Import-on-Demand):

===> does not work, does not import the style

**My question: is there a step-by-step guide to do what I want?**

I'm not the only one who wants to do that and has problems, here, [a guy on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/9d4il5/ant_design_css/), I found many others links and have tried every single thing, absolutely nothing worked.

Thanks!

Comment: did u ever fix this? im running into this issue. driving me crazy i dont want to import antd.min.css file

Answer (score 3):

```
import {Button} from 'antd'
import 'antd/lib/button/style';
```

worked for me...

what do you mean by

> '===> does not import the style.`

???

Comment: I mean what I said ^^ It simply does not imports the styles, meaning that I end up with a Button component that is just an HTML button, without the fancy css that goes with it. Note that I don't get any error while importing, so it looks like it does import the file but no styling applied to my button

Answer (score 3):

```
import { Spin, Icon } from 'antd';
import 'antd/lib/spin/style/css';
```

worked for me `antd version 3.17.0`

Answer (score 2):

You could try to import the index of the antd css file itself, like this:

`import 'antd/lib/spin/style/index.css';`

Answer (score 1):

In your global style.css file, try:

```
@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';
```